# Java How to pass the value from one class to another class

Tags: java

I want the result of value variable to be passed into another class.Also i should not change the return type of compute from void to String

```
public class One {

  private String value = null;
   public void compute(){
       Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Enter the String");
       value = s.next();

   }
   public String calculate(){

       System.out.println("In Calculate.........."+value);
       return value;
   }
   public static void main(String[] args){
       One o = new One();
       o.compute();
       o.calculate();
   }    
}

public class Two {
    public static void main(String[] args){
      System.out.println(new One().calculate());

    }
}
```

It is returning null values

It is printing like this

```
In Calculate..........null
null
```

Comment: in one class reate an reference of the other class and pass the variable to an appropriate setter in the other class. easy

Comment: you cannot have two public classes in a single file... :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you:

```
public class two
{
     public static void main(String[] args){
          One one=new One();
          one.compute();
          System.out.println(one.calculate());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to call compute before calling calculate. 
This should do the trick:

```
public class Two {
    public static void main(String[] args){
      One one = new One();
      one.compute();
      System.out.println(one.calculate());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This will always return null , as you are not calling `one.Compute()` in two

the correct call should be something like

```
public class Two {
    public static void main(String[] args){
          One o = new One();
          o.compute();

         System.out.println(o.calculate());

    }
}
```

or

```
you need to modify code of One to call compute in the constructor
```

Answer (score 1):

**First of all two main methods are not allowed in a single project!!**

Next you are not assigning any value to variable `value`  how do you expect it to print it for you?
You need to do the following.

```
public class Two {
    public static void main(String[] args){
      One myOne = new One();
       myOne.compute();
      //enter some value and then print
      System.out.println(new One().calculate());

    }
```

Lastly `value` is an instance variabble and is automatically assigned default value(null for String). So no need to explicitly assign.